# How to restart a crashed chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have written a chrome app to work at a kiosk system which gets started by the *--app-id* command-line switch. Unfortunately it is crashing a very few times (like twice a day) and the crashes are non-repeatable. Now i am trying to ensure it will get restarted after crash. So i wrote a batch script which checks if chrome is running and will restart the app if it's not.

My problem is that if the app crashes it will become deactivated on chrome, so when the shortcut gets called, it only opens a browser window instead of running the (deactivated) app. The folowing options i have in mind to solve my problem:

a) Disabling the behavour of chrome of disabling extensions which crashed

b) Re-enabling my extension/app on launch by command-line switch

c) Using the *--load-and-launch-app* command-line switch

With a) and b) i didn't find a soultion with web search. At c) i don't know how to set the path of *--load-and-launch-app* on Windows. It seems to expect a relative path but from which path? I tried every possibility but couldn't get it. So furthermore i don't know if it will solve my prob or if Chrome will also deactivate the app by it's path?

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does the crash appear at chrome://crashes? If so, file a bug with as much detail as possible about what might be causing it.

Comment: "c:\Users\scheib\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe" --load-and-launch-app=d:\src\chrome-app-samples\window-state

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The list at chrome://crashes is empty. Maybe it's because the app crashes at restart wich is done after an idle time of a minute. The --load-and-launch-app response you posted i have tried already but it didn't work. It looks like this at my sys: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --load-and-launch-app=c:\Users\ronninger\Desktop\app

Comment: Is it your app that is crashing or chrome itself? If it is your app you will get a little bubble telling you and chrome the browser should still be alright. If chrome is crashing we'd love to know the details at http://crbug.com. To get chrome://crashes to show chrome crashes you need to turn on error reporting which you can do under the Privacy settings with "Automatically send usage statistics and crash reports to Google".

Comment: Also, what version are you using? I just checked --load-and-launch-app and it was fine for me. We have fixed some bugs with it in the past month or so, and I am using a very fresh build, so maybe you're version doesn't have some needed fixes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I turned on crash reporting allready but got no entry. Like i said it appears to happen very randomly so i don't have any further details on this. The versions i have tested so far are 21, 26 and currently 28.0.1500.71. But luckily i solved the prob by writing another extension which checks if the app is running and starts it if not. I start this extension in kiosk mode and let it work as the newtab page.